# subclassing CCNode, blitzing image with glTexImage2D

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I've subclassed CCNode and would like to blitz an image stored in a member GLubyte* buffer on each draw call. This results in a black square being drawn, and a sibling CCLabel node is now also completely black.

So there are two issues:

1. Why isn't the square white? I'm memset-ing the buffer to 0xffffffff.
2. There must be something wrong with my OpenGL calls in the draw method, since it affects the drawing of another node. Can anyone say what?

data initialization:

```
exponent = e;
width = 1 << exponent;
height = 1 << exponent;
imageData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));
memset(imageData, 0xff, 4 * width * height * sizeof(GLubyte));
```

draw method:

```
- (void) draw
{
  float w = 100.0f;

  GLfloat vertices[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
       w, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,    w, 0.0f,
       w,    w, 0.0f
  };

  const GLshort texture_coordinates[] = {
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    0, 1,
    1, 1,
  };

  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, width, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
  glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, texture_coordinates);

  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

Comment: I've solved the blocks color issue by using   glDisableClientState/glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY); around the code in draw. This makes sense since [GL_TEXTURE_2D GL_VERTEX_ARRAY GL_COLOR_ARRAY GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY] are enabled by default for each draw call, and of those i do not need GL_COLOR_ARRAY. However, the siblin CCLabel node is still rendered in black.

Comment: Generally when drawing one thing affects something that draws later, it's because you didn't reset some state that you changed. I don't see anything obvious in your code above, so it might be somewhere else in your code. How are you drawing the label? Also, here's a fun fact - the word is "blit" not "blitz". It's an abbreviation of ["Block Image Transfer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit).

Answer (score 0):

you need to generate a texture object before filling it with data. That is, somewhere in initialization, you need to call:

```
int myTexture; // this is class member variable

glGenTextures(1, &myTexture); // generates an empty texture object

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myTexture); // activate the texture

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// makes sure there are no mipmaps (you only specify level 0, in case
// the texture is scaled during rendering, that could result in black square)

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
// this allocates the texture, but specifies no data
```

Later, when drawing (instead of your glTexImage2D() call), you need to activate your texture and specify it's data using glTexSubImage2D() (that doesn't allocate new storage for the texture).

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myTexture); // activate the texture
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
// this specifies texture data without allocating new storage
```

Calling glTex(Sub)Image2D without first binding the texture would a) result in an OpenGL error, or b) overwrite some other texture that is active at the moment - might be texture of the sibling label node.

Hope this helps :)